# Not able to extract screen name when analysing trending hashtag on R

Tags: r, twitter, hashtag

I have recently started learning to use R. I am trying to analyze the tweets consisting of #squidgame. I have finished the authentification and collected the tweets. However, when I try to find the unique screen names tweeting about the topic, I keep getting NULL as the result. That is the same case with the location too.

```
unique(squid_game$screenName)
unique(squid_game$location)
```

Just to be sure I tried analysing #netflix and #parisfashionweek and got the same results.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong or what step I am missing?

I would also appreciate it if someone could suggest resources for beginners to self learn R.

Thank you very much for taking the time to assist.

Comment: Hi, could you provide us the squid_game data.frame or list you use ? We just need few elements to understand the structure and values inside. This post has some tips for sharing this kind of information : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, here is a CSV file of the data frame and I see that the data frame shows screen names. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/184U1JUAQY3GUg2AQHyV4iySo6X9zbY4Y1g1oZZnmkPk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Resource to learn R: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/

Comment: Thank you for the resource.

Comment: Thanks for the dataset, but how do you import it into R ? I bet the column names are not assigned and thus `data.frame$colname` won't work. Also there is no `location` column in your dataset, do you create one ?

Comment: I extracted the tweets and exported the data frame to CSV format so that I could share the list I was using.